# Unable to install Review board on CentOS

Tags: centos, review-board, centos8

I created CentOS virtual OS in Hyper-V Manager on Windows 10 and set up appropriate proxy.
Then I followed guide here https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-review-board-on-centos-7-2/ and all is fine until I get to "sudo yum install ReviewBoard memcached -y", where I get error

'''
No match for argument: ReviewBoard".
'''

I googled the error but found no solution.

Comment: Did you exec this command before: `sudo yum install epel-release -y`?

Comment: Yes. Did it again and it said "already installed, nothing to do."

Comment: Try to execute command like this: `sudo yum -y install ReviewBoard memcached`

Comment: I get same error (no match for argument ReviewBoard. Unable to find a match), plus memcached is already installed.

Comment: You can try to install it by hand: `yum localinstall https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/r/ReviewBoard-2.5.17-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: I have CentOS 8, is ReviewBoard not supported on this version? Because I can't find it on <https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/r/>.

Comment: Probably this is the case. But IMO you can use package from 7 and install it by hand

Comment: I tried it and and got error that I don't have some other python packages, which I cannot install (get same error for them - "unable to find a match"). I will try CentOS 7 and report later.

Comment: Working as expected, thank you for the help!